# How do I get Bootstrap to center content so items stay horizontally compact?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

I have content that I want centered on the page. Inside a div I want items to stay close together (top image), but when the page is resized wider Bootstrap adds space (bottom image) - trying to put them on new column boundaries?

How do I get Bootstrap 5 to keep them compacted to center of page?

This:
[image]

Instead of this:
[image]

```
<div class="container text-center center-container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div>
                image
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            Some texty bits
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div>
                image
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `flexbox` with Bootstrap's `flex` utility classes.

You can also use the `col-{breakpoint}-auto` class in grid to achieve variable width columns.

#### Solution and demos

https://codesandbox.io/s/bootstrap-flex-example-k7iyn3

With flex:

```html
<link 
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  rel="stylesheet"
  integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
/>
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center gap-4">
    <div>
      <img src='https://via.placeholder.com/150'>
    </div>
    <div class="p-4 bg-info">
      Some texty bits
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src='https://via.placeholder.com/150'>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

With grid:

```html
<link 
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  rel="stylesheet"
  integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row gx-0 justify-content-sm-center gap-4">
    <div class="col col-sm-auto">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-auto p-4 bg-info">
      Some texty bits
    </div>
    <div class="col col-sm-auto">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example to reduce the gap between the columns using bootstrap 5.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row g-2">
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="p-3 border bg-light">Custom column padding</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="p-3 border bg-light">Custom column padding</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="p-3 border bg-light">Custom column padding</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`g-` is the space between the columns, and it is known as gutter space. Always set the max width, if you don't want the main containers to span across the devices especially in wider screens